# JS Logical And / Or

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

Can someone explain to me why both of these alert 'True'? The logical OR makes sense I think - The OR short circuits after the first test: 100 != 90, therefor it is true. By why does the AND short circuit after the first test and not keep going?

```
if (100 != 90 && 100 && 190 && 200 && 290){
    alert("true");
} else {
    alert("false");
}

if (100 != 90 || 100 || 190 || 200 || 290){
    alert("true");
} else {
    alert("false");
}
```

EDIT: THANK YOU EVERYONE FOR YOUR HELP! BASED ON YOUR SUGGESTIONS, I THINK I WILL AMMEND MY CODE TO THIS:

```
var trains = [90,100,190,200,290];
var testValue = 100;

if (trains.indexOf(testValue) >= 0){
    alert("true");
}
```

Comment: `if (100 != 90 && 100 && 190 && 200 && 290)` all of these are truthy. What did you expect to see happen?

Comment: I suspect the mistake you are making is that you think `if (100 != 90 && 100)` is equivalent to `if (100 != 90 && 100 != 100)` which it simply isn't

Comment: Exactly what I needed Matt, thank you

Comment: I wrongly assumed that they meant the same thing. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will evaluate to true:

```
if (100 != 90 && 100 && 190 && 200 && 290)
```

Because each part is truthy. Any non-zero value in javascript is consider to be equivalent to true. So you have:

```
if (true && true && true && true && true)
```

Which is, obviously, true. It's not short circuiting, because none of the values are false.

I suspect the mistake you've made is to think that this:

```
if (100 != 90 && 100)
```

Is doing the same thing as this:

```
if (100 != 90 && 100 != 100)
```

Which is simply not how the syntax works. It's easy to say in words *"if 100 doesn't equal 90 and doesn't equal 100"* and understand what that means, but in javascript (and most other languages) you have to be explicit.

Now obviously this gets really tedious if you have a value that you need to compare with a long list of values, for example:

```
if (x != 90 && x != 100 && x != 190...)
```

And in a case like that, it's usually easier to put all your values into an array and instead ask if `x` is contained (or not) in that array:

```
var values = [90,100,190,...]

if (!values.some(function(e) { return e === x; })) {
    // the value x is not in the array values
}
```

Comment: Thanks for expanding on your answer Matt. You've given me an idea. Can I add all the values to an array and say something like this: (SEE EDIT IN INITIAL QUESTION)

Answer (score 0):

For the &&, the first 100 != 90 evaluates to true. Then, the integers are implicitly converted to bools, where 0 = false, true otherwise. The true will carry through the numbers, of which none are 0.

Your comment about || is correct.